# Tomcat 7 ignoring setenv.sh

Tags: tomcat

Running tomcat

INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.78

on

CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

Extensive searching has not revealed the answer to my question. There are many pages describing what to do, but none describing how to troubleshoot or whether anyone else has this problem

In

```
/usr/share/tomcat/bin
```

I created a setenv.sh containing

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xss112m -Dsome.random.variable=random1"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dsome.random.variable2=random1"
```

I do not see the variable definitions at the head of my catalina.out (Info: Command line argument). I also tried using JAVA_OPTS instead of CATALINA_OPTS.

This is the bin directory listing:

```
[root@localhost tomcat]# ls -l bin
total 80
-rw-r--r-- 1 root tomcat 29182 Jun  9 19:57 bootstrap.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root tomcat  1647 Jun  9 19:57 catalina-tasks.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root tomcat   133 Jul 31 21:26 setenv.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   38548 Jun  9 19:57 tomcat-juli.jar
```

I resorted to changing JAVA_OPTS in

```
 /usr/share/tomcat/conf/tomcat.conf
```

This worked fine.

Does anyone know what I may have done wrong?

Comment: the executable flag? `chmod +x setenv.sh`

Answer (score 1):

`bin/setenv.sh` is called by `bin/catalina.sh`. However, Tomcat on CentOS 6 does not have `bin/catalina.sh`. So, you may have to write `CATALINA_OPTS` to another file, for example, `/etc/tomcat7/tomcat7.conf`.